# Looking for a faster way to make calculations on a varying number of rows within different factors in a data.frame

Tags: r

I'm looking for a faster way than using a for-loop to select a varying number of rows within different factors/levels in a dataframe with a following manipulation of the rows.

The data I'm working on contains a number of cells and a larger and varying number of points within each cell. Given the characteristics of the cell, I have to remove different numbers of points from these cells.

The simple example given here contains two tables: table1 with the cells and their characteristics and table2 with points and their corresponding cell number. Column 2 in each table contains information on how many points to remove from the dataset. Column 3 in table 2 gives the density of points within the cell they're in. Here is the example:

```
table1 <- data.frame(matrix(c(2,3,1,1,3,0),nrow=3))
table2 <- data.frame(matrix(c(3:1,3:1,3,2,rep(NA,8),3,3,2,3,3,2,3,3),nrow=8))
table2[,2] <- table1[match(table2[,1], table1[,1]),2]
colnames(table1) <- c("cell_index","pts_to_drop_from_cells")
colnames(table2) <- c("cell_index","pts_to_drop","density_of_points_in_cell")
```

My main dataset contains tens of thousands of cells and millions of points so speed is really important. There are two solutions that I have come up with so far:

The fastest solution I have come up with, Approach1:

```
#first calculate the probability of each particle to be dropped given the density in the cell
table2[,4] <- table2[,2]/table2[,3]
colnames(table2)[4] <- "prob"
#then calculate a logical vector for indexing the data.frame
#I use sample() to randomly determine whether this point should be 
#dropped/kept given the probability in table2[,4]
vect1 <- runif(1) <= table2[,4]
vect1
table2[vect1==T,]
```

However, I'd much rather select all points from one cell (meaning all rows in table2 with the same cell_index) and sample from the selected rows the number of rows to be dropped. Reason is that if "runif()" is used on each point individually it introduces more randomness than I like. The best solution I've found for this approach is a quite slow one, Approach2:

```
list1 <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(table1)){
  ## select all points from the same cell
  a <- table2[table2[,1]==i,]
  ## randomly select a number of those points
  b <- sample(nrow(a), a[,2] )
  test <- length(b) > 0
  ## save the results in a list
  list1[[i]] <- as.numeric(rownames(if (!length(test)) { a }else{ a[b,] } ))
}
## combine the list to a vector
vect2 <- unlist(list1)
## the result, a table with all the dropped points
table2[vect2,]
```

Is there a way to code Approach2 in a way that comes even close to the speed of Approach1? If so, what would it look like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `mapply`, for which I can't guarantee to be the fastest thing around. A `data.table` solution has basically no competition.

```
mapply(split(table1, table1$cell_index), split(table2, table2$cell_index), 
          FUN = function(wan, tu) {
  keep <- nrow(tu) - wan$pts_to_drop_from_cells
  indices <- sample(1:nrow(tu), size = keep, replace = FALSE)
  tu[indices, ]
}, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

$`1`
  cell_index pts_to_drop density_of_points_in_cell
3          1           0                         2
6          1           0                         2

$`2`
  cell_index pts_to_drop density_of_points_in_cell
5          2           1                         3
2          2           1                         3

$`3`
[1] cell_index                pts_to_drop               density_of_points_in_cell
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Roman. However, it unfortunately turns out to be slower than approach2: `table2 <- rbind(table2,table2,table2,table2,table2)`
`system.time(rep("insert approach2",100000000))`
user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02 
`system.time(rep("insert mapply-approach",100000000))`
user  system elapsed 
   4.62    1.20    5.81